# Listen for ImageView clicks in LinearLayout

Tags: java, android, android-linearlayout, android-imageview, onclicklistener

I am adding imageViews to a LinearLayout, for some reason the clickListener wasn't working for each imageView, so I decided to try and add tags to the imageView then add it to the LinearLayout, then when the linearLayout was clicked I wanted to check the views tag to find out which imageView was pressed. This is not working, specifically the view tag is always null. I would like to be able to differentiate between which image was clicked.

The following takes an arrayList of the paths to each image, the images are loading to the screen fine.

```
private void displayImages(ArrayList<String> al) {
    final int THUMBSIZE = 640;//was originally 64

    linearLayout1.removeAllViews();
    for (int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++){
        Bitmap ThumbImage = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(
                Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/ImageSpace/"+al.get(i)), 
                        THUMBSIZE, THUMBSIZE);
        Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),ThumbImage);
        imageView = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
        imageView.setBackground(d);
        //linearLayout1.removeAllViews();
        //imageView.setTag(i+"");
        linearLayout1.addView(imageView);
        linearLayout1.getChildAt(i).setTag(i+"");
    }

}
```

This is the linearLayout click listener:

```
    linearLayout1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "yeh", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.v("TAG","views tag: "+v.getTag());
        }
    });
```

XML Layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:contentDescription="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
            android:onClick="test"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Also, I am initializing the imageView I use like this,

```
imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
```

This seems like it may be incorrect, as it would only refer to one imageView, this may be the problem.

Comment: I think that the tag you're getting when doing v.getTag() it´s the linearlayout itself and not the imageview. Try adding the OnClickListener to every imageview inside the loop and not setting it to the linearLayout1.

Comment: you just need to set Uniq id to your imageview.

Comment: I had UIImageView in linearlayout and I added setOnClickListener to the image view, which works fine. Can you double check whether you can use it?

Comment: I believe that UIImageView is iOS not Android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to set Id to each `ImageView` that you adding into your `Linear Layout`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++){
    Bitmap ThumbImage = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(
            Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/ImageSpace/"+al.get(i)), 
                    THUMBSIZE, THUMBSIZE);
    Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),ThumbImage);
    imageView = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
    imageView.setId(i);
    imageView.setBackground(d);
    //linearLayout1.removeAllViews();
    //imageView.setTag(i+"");
    linearLayout1.addView(imageView);
     imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v1) {

                    System.out.print("Imageview clikcked Path!::::" +al.get(v1.getId()));

                    }

                }
            });
}
```

And when you click into any `ImageView` to get Particular data by getting id of that View. try this out.